# Angular2 & Atom - Using Question Mark Syntax '?' in HTML causes HTML tag discoloration

Tags: html, angular, atom-editor

I'm not sure if this is the right place for this question but there seems to be an `atom-editor` tag and none of the related questions I've have been removed so here goes.

When I use the [Safe Navigation / Null Property Operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#the-safe-navigation-operator-and-null-property-paths) (`?.`) it messing up the rest of my `html`

But this is what I mean

> #### Before
>
> [image]

> #### After
>
> [image]

This makes it harder on the eyes when I use question marks and I'd like to be able to use them without the discoloration of the everything below the `?`'s

I assume the issues lies with one of the following:

1. My **Syntax Theme**

I'm using the **Lucario** Theme in the example and tried changing it out with other themes but this doesn't seem to be the issue.

2. The **atom package** `language-html`

I think this is the issue because it seems to be the part of **Atom** that supports the **HTML Language** it's self. I thought this could be corrected in the **Non Word Characters** option

[image]

so I tried the **default** above and tried removing the `?` from **Non Word Characters** option like

[image]

But it didn't work and I also restarted atom to make sure but nothing seems to work.

Any tips, suggestions or fixes for my problem?

Thanks

Comment: I'd post an [issue](https://github.com/atom/language-html/issues) on GitHub to have the developers look into it

Comment: check this one => [Why we use "?" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42364248/3545036)