# Why use "?" operator in template binding?

Tags: angular

When I use `?`, the binding works well. If I remove it, it doesn't show anything in the view.

```
<span class="subhead">{{project?.category}}</span>
```

Can you please tell me the difference? Is it a good practice to use it this way?

Comment: This also applies to hero?.name.  Adding comment here so search will find this question.

Comment: `project && project.category`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

When Angular renders the view before `project` got a value assigned, it causes an exception. `?.` stops evaluating when `project` is `null` or `undefined`, which usually happens when data is fetched async, for example from the server which can take quite some time.

The next time change detection recognizes a change, the bindings will be re-evaluated. When `project` then has a value it will bind `project.category`.

Comment: Can we add a default value until the data is loaded?

Comment: `[prop]="project?.category !== null ? project.category : defaultValue"`

Answer (score 36):

`?` is the safe navigation operator. It checks whether the variable is `null` or `undefined` so that our template won't try to select a property of something falsy.

More info: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: Small detail... The safe navigation operator is not the same as elvis operator. Elvis operator refers to the ternary operator, which is not the same as safe navigation operator (which I know you know) :)

Comment: @AJT_82 ah thank you for the warning! I'll remove it to not cause any confusion.

Comment: Seems like it is an Elvis operator according to to Wikipedia. [Elvis operator is the ternary operator with its second operand omitted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator). Add it back! Will never remember to call it "safe navigation operator".

Comment: @echonax No problem. I was educated about this a while back, so I have referred to this wrong myself uptil then :P I also noticed there was this blog post that used the `elvis` operator before (which I have referred to before). Now the blog post has been changed and poster has used `safe navigation operator` instead: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/elvis-operator-in-angular-2.0 As you can see the url still contains `elvis` operator but content has changed :)

Comment: @runyards Let's agree that they're in the same family but it's a strong claim to state that they're the same :-) take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6613952/is-there-a-null-coalescing-elvis-operator-or-safe-navigation-operator-in-javas

Comment: Yeah your definitely right, is the equivalent of safe navigation operator. Would be interesting to see how it actually works underneath though. If it returns some default value for various types it would be an evils operator though.

Comment: Just small correction: Accessing a falsy value's property isn't necessarily bad = producing TypeError. Consider `''.length` which is totally valid operation on falsy value.

Answer (score 4):

This safe navigation operator prevents the view from rendering before getting the value.

We can fix the error of undefined or null values in view templates by the following three methods.
Obviously other ways are there.

Method 1: Using Safe navigation operator

```
<span class="subhead">{{project?.category}}</span>
```

Method 2: Using async pipe

```
<span class="subhead">{{(project | async )?.category}}</span>
```

If you are getting the value through `@Input()` decorator from app component, you can simplify the code like this in the app component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <app-project [project]="project | async"></app-project>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App { ... }
```

And you can use the template as below in the child component(i.e project component for example)

```
<span class="subhead">{{project.category}}</span>
```

Method 3: Restricting in the view by `*ngIf` structural directive

```
<span class="subhead" *ngIf="project">{{project.category}}</span>
```

[Safe Navigation in angular](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)

[Async pipe](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#async-pipe)

Comment: That Method 2 saved my day, thanks man :)