# Error while iterating with *ngFor in angular2

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have json response like, Im trying to iterate over json response but it is giving errors

I don't know if angular2 don't suport iteration like this as I'm new to angular2

**serive call**

```
return this.http.post(this.url,params)
        .map(res => res.json())
```

Assigning response to travelGuides

```
.subscribe(travelGuides => {
        this.travelGuides = travelGuides.resultData;         
}
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "resultCode": 1,
  "resultData": {
    "TravelGuide": [
      {
        "Help": "TravelGuide",
        "IsDocument": "1",
        "EventType": "Success",
        "Category": "HOTEL",
        "SupplierType": "SUPTYPE-0-0-11",
        "HotelSrno": "HOTEL-0-0-62",
        "Name": "Radisson Blu Plaza Bangkok",
        "Optional": "0",
        "Fileupload1": "hotel.jpg",
        "FileUpload1Path": "/Documents/MasterData/HOTEL/HOTEL-0-0-62/hotel.jpg"
      },
      {
        "Help": "TravelGuide",
        "IsDocument": "1",
        "EventType": "Success",
        "Category": "HOTEL",
        "SupplierType": "SUPTYPE-0-0-11",
        "HotelSrno": "HOTEL-0-0-62",
        "Name": "Radisson Blu Plaza Bangkok",
        "Optional": "0",
        "Fileupload1": "hotel.jpg",
        "FileUpload1Path": "/Documents/MasterData/HOTEL/HOTEL-0-0-62/hotel.jpg"
      }
    ],
    "TravelGuide_Img": [
      {
        "Help": "TravelGuide_Img",
        "IsDocument": "0",
        "EventType": "Success",
        "Category": "HOTEL",
        "Name": "hotelimage.jpg",
        "TextoverImg": "Radisson Blu ",
        "Textbox2": "/Documents/MasterData/HOTELIMG/HOTELIMG-0-0-1",
        "AltText": "Radisson Blu ",
        "path": "/Documents/MasterData/HOTELIMG/HOTELIMG-0-0-1/hotelimage.jpg",
        "ImageCategoryName": "IMGCATG",
        "HotelName": "Radisson Blu Plaza Bangkok",
        "ImageSize": "Medium",
        "ImageResolution": "IMGSIZE-0-0-1",
        "ImageCategory": "IMGCATG",
        "Hotel": "HOTEL-0-0-62",
        "ImageSize_srno": "IMGSIZE-0-0-1",
        "ImageResolution1": "RESOLUTIO-0-0-1"
      },
      {
        "Help": "TravelGuide_Img",
        "IsDocument": "0",
        "EventType": "Success",
        "Category": "HOTEL",
        "Name": "hotelimage.jpg",
        "TextoverImg": "Text Over Image",
        "Textbox2": "/Documents/MasterData/HOTELIMG/HOTELIMG-0-0-2",
        "AltText": "Text Over Image",
        "path": "/Documents/MasterData/HOTELIMG/HOTELIMG-0-0-2/hotelimage.jpg",
        "ImageCategoryName": "IMGCATG",
        "HotelName": "Pullman Bangkok Hotel G",
        "ImageSize": "Medium",
        "ImageResolution": "IMGSIZE-0-0-1",
        "ImageCategory": "IMGCATG",
        "Hotel": "HOTEL-0-0-63",
        "ImageSize_srno": "IMGSIZE-0-0-1",
        "ImageResolution1": "RESOLUTIO-0-0-2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

here is *ngFor im trying

```
 <div *ngFor="let travelguide of travelGuides">
   {{travelguide.TravelGuide.Category}}
 </div>
```

but getting this

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

also tried

```
 <div *ngFor="let travelguide of travelGuides.TravelGuide">
   {{travelguide.Category}}
 </div>
```

for this getting error

```
Cannot read property 'TravelGuide' of undefined
```

Comment: how do you assign travelGuides,show the code

Comment: where is the service call which populates travel guides

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya check the answer

Comment: @RahulSingh added in question please check .subscribe

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya i want to know the call you make to http get

Comment: @RahulSingh Ohh, sorry. Added service call in question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `travelGuides` is assigned asynchronously, your code should be like

```
<div *ngFor="let travelguide of travelGuides?.TravelGuide">
 {{travelguide?.Category}}
</div>
```

More info on safe navigation operator (?): [Why we use "?" operator in template binding in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42364184/5706293)

or

```
<div *ngIf="travelGuides && travelGuides.length && travelGuides.length > 0">
  <div *ngFor="let travelguide of travelGuides.TravelGuide">
   {{travelguide.Category}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are assigning the whole response to travelGuides, it should be ,

```
 <div *ngFor="let travelguide of travelGuides?.resultData.TravelGuide">
   {{travelguide.Category}}
 </div>
```

**EDIT**

Change the assignment part as,

```
.subscribe(travelGuides => {
        this.travelGuides = travelGuides.resultData.TravelGuide;         
}
```

and **`HTML`**

```
<div *ngFor="let travelguide of travelGuides?.TravelGuide">
 {{travelguide?.Category}}
</div>
```

Comment: I can't cause resultData have 2 arrays `TravelGuide` and `TravelGuide_Img` which I want in same div

Comment: Is it possible to iterarte it on same div if I  use `this.travelGuides = travelGuides.resultData.TravelGuide; ` and 

`this.travelGuide_Imgs = travelGuides.resultData.TravelGuide_Img;`

Comment: yeah you can do

Comment: But inner *NgFor iterates for same length as it's parent

Answer (score 0):

If your component model looks something like this:

```
this.responseData = {
  "resultCode": 1,
  "resultData": {
    "TravelGuide": [
      { somedata }, { somedata }, ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Your markup for *ngFor would look like:

```
<div *ngFor="let travelguide of responseData.resultData.TravelGuide">
  {{ travelguide.Category }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div *ngFor="let travelguide of travelGuides?.["TravelGuide"]">
 {{travelguide?.Category}}
 ....
</div>
```