# What does the angular 4 .? notation mean?

Tags: angular

My question is as in the title: what does the sign '.?' mean?

Can't find it in the docs, so that's why I'm here.

```
[image]="(user$ | async)?.photo"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why we use "?" operator in template binding in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364184/why-we-use-operator-in-template-binding-in-angular-2)

Comment: Maybe not duplicated, but related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Safe Navigation operator `?.` is used to avoid a `NullPointerException`. Typically when you have a reference to an object you might need to verify that it is not null before accessing methods or properties of the object. To avoid this, the safe navigation operator will simply return null instead of throwing an exception.

Easily confused with the `elvis operator` `?:`, but that's completely different and does not exist in JavaScript/TypeScript or Angular templating

Answer (score 1):

It is called **[`safe navigation`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)** or elvis operator, which checks the value is present

> The Angular safe navigation operator (?.) is a fluent and convenient
>   way to guard against null and undefined values in property paths. Here
>   it is, protecting against a view render failure if the user is
>   null.

Answer (score 1):

It's calle the safe navigator operator https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator and it's main purpose it's to avoid to access null or undefined object, which is really helpful when you're dealing with async data (as stated in your example).