# Strategy to display form while data is still loading with Angular 6

Tags: angular, http, angular6

When loading data via HTTP, I always get a lot of errors.

If you are loading an Object User, for instance, and you reference user.name, while requesting data via HTTP, console will give you an error, `unable to find name attribute on null`, or something like that.

You can fix this putting on the main div a boolean `loading`, like:

```
<div class="main" *ngIf="!loading">
  {{ user.name }}
</div>
```

But I am not satisfied with it, what I want is display an emtpy form, with a loader displaying, and as soon as I have the data, displaying it...

Is there an elegant way to do it ? (not something like `if user !== null ...` for each reference )

Comment: Have a look at this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364184/why-we-use-operator-in-template-binding-in-angular-2

Comment: ok, but `?` is sometimes, but do I really want to have all my user references with  `?`. Also, what about having several objects that should be null: user?.post?.comments ... not so great, isn't it ?

Comment: @JuliatzindelToro that's this, or `user && user.post && user.post.comments`, up to your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the safe navigation operator

```
{{ user?.name }}
```

Or Javascript's native way of dealing with undefined values

```
{{ user && user.name }}
```

Or you can display a loader, for instance this one

```css
.loader {
  margin: auto;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 2px solid coral;
  border-right: 2px solid transparent;
  animation: spin 0.7s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader"></div>
```

With your condition

```
<div *ngIf="!loading">{{ user.name }}</div>
<div class="loader" *ngIf="loading"></div>
```

Comment: ok, I am already using the last one, but as I was saying in my post, I don't want to hide the form. and putting ? everywhere is not so elegant, I would have hoped better :) nevermind ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: As I told on your question, that's either the Evlis operator `user?.post?.comments[0]?.content` or the native JS way `user && user.post && user.post.comments && user.post.comments[0] && user.post.comments[0].content`. So yes, the safe navigation operator is way more elegant.

Comment: yes, but there is nothing more elegant than the safe navigation operator

Comment: There's still a getter, but that's just moving the logic.