# Angular 4 [(ngModel)] to an array object

Tags: angular

I am working on an Angular 4 project, I currently have a *ngFor, and in the loop we are creating a new form (so I could end up with 2 or more forms)

The problem I am having is, the [(ngModel)] is not binding to the array key.

Code examples below:

Definition of the new Array:

public newItem: Array<{
        category_id: number,
        name: string,
        number_of_people_invited: number,
        number_of_people_confirmed: number
    }> = [];

then the form

```
<div *ngFor="let guestListItem of guestListItems; let i = index;">
    <form (submit)="doSubmit(i)" [name]="i">
    <ion-row ion-list>
        <ion-col size="6">
            <ion-item lines="none">
                <ion-input name="name"
                [(ngModel)]="newItem[i].name"
                style="border: none" type="text"
                placeholder="Family name"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col size="6">
            <ion-item lines="none">
                <ion-input name="number_of_people_invited"
                [(ngModel)]="newItem[i].number_of_people_invited"
                type="tel" placeholder="No. Guests"></ion-input>
                <ion-button type="submit" end>Add</ion-button>
            </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    </form>
</div>
```

The error am getting is: GuestListPage.html:20 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

this is line 20 : [(ngModel)]="newItem[i].name"

Comment: Your creating an empty array `newItem` and you're never adding items to this array. So `newItem[i]` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: Hi @fridoo, thanks for your reply, is there a way around this as I could have 3, 4 forms

Comment: You should say what you're really trying to achieve. What type and purpose have your `guestListItems`? Maybe you could use those to store the input data.

Comment: @user3057745, if you make a *ngFor="let guestListItem of guestListItems", Why do you not [(ngModel)]="guestListItem.name" ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is saying `newItem[i]` is `undefined` but your template is still trying to extract `name` from it. `newItem[i]` may be populated later, but at that point of evaluation it's still trying to pull out a value from something which is `undefined`, which obviously doesn't make sense.

Have you tried `[(ngModel)]="newItem[i]?.name"`

With the `?` Angular won't evaluate `newItem[i]` until it is not `null` or `undefined`.

[This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42364248/8351094) sums up the `?` decently.