# Use custom directive value to optionally display form element

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use the output from a custom validation directive in one element `<input>` to control the display of another element `<p>`, but can't figure out how to make it work. This is what I have so far:

Custom Directive (`no-special-chars-directive.ts`)

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { Validator, 
        FormControl, 
        NG_VALIDATORS, 
        ValidationErrors} from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: '[appNoSpecialChars]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: NoSpecialCharsDirective, multi: true}],
  exportAs: 'noSpecChars'
})
export class NoSpecialCharsDirective implements Validator{

  constructor() { }
  validate(c: FormControl): ValidationErrors {
    //console.log("input value: " + c.value);
    const hasSpecialChars = /[~!@#\^&*+=\-\[\]\';,/{}|\":<>\?\\()]/.test(c.value);
    const message = {
      'hasSpecialChars' : {
        'message': 'No Special Chars Allowed'
      }
    };
    return hasSpecialChars ? message : null;
  }
}
```

Here is the template: (`git-search.component.html`)

```
<h3>{{title}} - {{displayQuery}} -- (version: Template Driven)</h3>
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="sendQuery()">
  <div *ngFor="let key of modelKeys">
      {{key}} 
      <input  #myInput name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" [(ngModel)]="model[key]" required *ngIf="key==='q'" appNoSpecialChars/>
      <input  #myInput name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" [(ngModel)]="model[key]" minlength = '2' maxlength='4' *ngIf="key==='stars'" appNoSpecialChars />      
      <input  #myInput name="{{key}}" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" [(ngModel)]="model[key]" *ngIf="key!=='q' && key!=='stars'" appNoSpecialChars/> 
      <p *ngIf="!myForm[key].valid" >Not valid</p> 
  </div>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.valid">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

I want the `<p>` element to optionally display whenever there is invalid input in the preceding `<input>`. I've tried multiple permutations for the `*ngIf` statement and in the inputs themselves, but haven't found anything that works yet. Everything worked fine before I started playing around with the optional display of the `<p>` element.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line

```
<p *ngIf="!myForm[key].valid" >Not valid</p>
```

to

```
<p *ngIf="!myForm.form.get(key)?.valid" >Not valid</p>
```

`myForm.form` gets the default/in your case only `FormGroup` which holds all `FormControls`.

The `?` is like a special null coalesce operator ([Why we use "?" operator in template binding in angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42364184/why-we-use-operator-in-template-binding-in-angular-2)) which prevents errors in case `myForm.form.get(key)` is NULL.

you can see it in action here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-liqgux

Comment: Quick follow up question . . . How would I access the value returned from the directive, from outside of the element hosting the directive? Also, from inside the element hosting the directive?

Comment: I don't know from the top of my hat but you should ask this as another/seperate question.